# Data received through ajax, not inserting data into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am sending two unique ids into a php file via ajax. The thing is ajax is sending data to php successfully, though, insert query isn't working there ....
Here is the JS script:

```
<!-- JS script for setting and getting task and employee id -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.alcbtn').click(function() {
        var ts =  $(this).data('task');
        $('.allocatetaskmodal table').find('.alctask').attr('data-task', ts);
    });

    $('.alctask').click(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        var emp = $(this).data('emp');
        var task = $(this).data('task');

        $.post('tescript.php', { emp : emp , task : task }, function(value) {
            console.log("data sent");
            t.text('Allocated');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the php script:

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';

$emp_id = $_POST['emp'];
$tsk_id = $_POST['task'];

$ins = "insert into taskempmapping (task_id,employee_id) values ($tsk_id,$emp_id)";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$ins);
?>
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="modal fade allocatetaskmodal" id="allocatetsk" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header prj-gc">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title prj-gc" id="myModalLabel">Allocate Employee</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body prj-gc">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>Employee ID</th>
          <th>Employee Name</th>
          <th>Employee Designation</th>
          <th>Pending Tasks</th> <!-- use count in query to fetch pending tasks -->
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

       <tbody>
<!-- Php code to fetch all the records of employees whose designation is not PM or TL --> 

         <?php 
         $query = "select employee_id, employee_name, employee_designation from employee where employee_designation!= 'Project Manager' AND employee_designation!='Team Leader'";
         $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
             echo '<tr>
                 <td>'.$row['employee_id'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['employee_name'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['employee_designation'].'</td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs alctask" data-emp="'.$row['employee_id'].'"  href="#">Allocate</a></td>
             </tr>';
         }
      ?>

   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Please help me in this. Thank you!

Comment: what was inserted data in mysql after ajax call ?

Comment: do `if(!$run){ echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);}` anything from that?

Comment: Did you check $emp_id and $tsk_id on php side using var_dump?

you could also try var dump on $run and post the errors you're getting

try putting values inside ' ' like this

    ...
    values ('$task_id','$emp_id')";
    ...

Comment: I stood in the question long enough and no response from anyone's comments; see the answer below. If that doesn't solve this, then you'll need to tell them that. Good luck, I'm out.

Comment: I am trying to insert employee id and task id into taskempmapping table @Fred-ii-

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors, though I'm getting data sent msg on console @Fred-ii-

Comment: Few things to try: 1) error reporting 2) mysqli_error 3) console 4) var_dump 5) HTML source

Comment: As @Cgdl mentioned, you should check the values that you are receiving on the PHP side with var_dump(). Try this in your PHP file:

var_dump($emp_id);
var_dump($tsk_id);

Then, in the JavaScript .post() function, try this:

console.log(value);

Comment: After doing this and checking my console.log  I am getting all source code instead of actual values ... @Daniel.Schroeder

Comment: OK sorry just echo $emp_id; and echo $tsk_id; my bad

Comment: In php file? @Daniel.Schroeder

Comment: When opening php file I'm getting undefined index notice instead of displaying $emp_id and $task_id values @Daniel.Schroeder

Comment: This is weird, but you must echo the values of the variables in the PHP file then you are reading them with the console.log(value) in the javascript file. That will tell you what values you are actually trying to insert into the DB

Comment: echoing these two variables am only seeing source code instead of values @Daniel.Schroeder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134924/discussion-between-daniel-schroeder-and-aisha-salman).

Comment: Please check our discussion room .... @Daniel.Schroeder

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE TO ANSWER**

OK, new plan. I think we've established from our private chat that the data is not getting to the PHP file. Copy these three files into the same directory and see if you get the same results I do.

First up, index.php:

```
<?php

$result = [
  [
    'employee_id' => 1,
    'employee_name' => 'bill',
    'employee_designation' => 'webdesigner'
  ],
  [
    'employee_id' => 2,
    'employee_name' => 'sam',
    'employee_designation' => 'manager'
  ],
  [
    'employee_id' => 3,
    'employee_name' => 'mike',
    'employee_designation' => 'boss'
  ],
];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <th>Employee ID</th>
              <th>Employee Name</th>
              <th>Employee Designation</th>
              <th>Pending Tasks</th> <!-- use count in query to fetch pending tasks -->
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

           <tbody>
             <?php 
                 foreach ($result as $row)
                 {
                     echo '<tr>
                         <td>'.$row['employee_id'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$row['employee_name'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$row['employee_designation'].'</td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs alctask" data-emp="'.$row['employee_id'].'"  href="#">Allocate</a></td>
                     </tr>';
                 }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Next, script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.alctask').click(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        var emp = $(this).data('emp');
        var task = 12;

        console.log('emp in JS = ' + emp);
        console.log('task in JS= ' + task)

        $.post('tescript.php', { emp : emp , task : task }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, tescript.php:

```
<?php 

$emp_id = $_REQUEST['emp'];
$tsk_id = $_REQUEST['task'];

echo 'emp_id in PHP = ' . $emp_id . PHP_EOL;
echo 'tsk_id in PHP = ' . $tsk_id . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

When I click 'Allocate' on the first employee, I get this in the console:

```
emp in JS = 1
task in JS= 12
emp_id in PHP = 1
tsk_id in PHP = 12
```

I didn't implement your way of getting the task_id so I just set it to 12 each time, but it doesn't matter for the sake of the example. Try that out, and see if you get similar results as me. Then, we can work through why your other script isn't getting similar answers.

Comment: No, I'm only seeing values set in .alctask click handler and not seeing the values that are coming from php file .... @Daniel.Scroeder

Answer (score 0):

Try using '' and capital letters when inserting values into table

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO `taskempmapping` (task_id,employee_id) VALUES ('$tsk_id','$emp_id')";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$ins);
```

Comment: *"and capital letters"* - that doesn't matter. As for the quoting; that's only if their data are string. OP isn't responding to comments so we'll see if they'll respond to yours.

Comment: Thanks for new info, yes perhaps connection is problem.